# How to get controls depending upon the iteration count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get clientId dynamically depending upon the iteration count e.g

```
var clientID = "<%=NumericTextBox" + 1 + ".ClientID %>";
var id = document.getElementById(clientID);
```

but if i try to use above statements to get the control it throws ";expected", ")exppected" errors what is the proper way of getting the control?

Comment: which line is the error being thrown? does it say which character? this compiles just fine in a web browser

Comment: Do you really have an HTML element with the id value `<%=NumericTextBox1.ClientID %>`? That looks like some attempt at using a templating language and mix it with JavaScript or something? I feel like there's more going on here than you've explained.

Comment: May we assume that you're using MVC and .NET, or what language is evaluating the <% %> sections?

Comment: It throws error at line 1 error is:Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have numeric textbox control in asp.net. If you need to get the id of it, you can use

```
var clientId = '<%= NumericTextBox.ClientId %>';
var txt = document.getElementById(clientId);
```

If the textbox is inside a grid control, you would usually append the number at the end or at the beginning like this

```
var clientId = 'ctl_0' + i + '<%= NumericTextBox.ClientId %>'
```

You can check the id that the framework is rendering by going to view source.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what server-side language and template engine you're using, but I think you're using it incorrectly and that's what's giving the error. In most languages, this will parse as a server-side templating directive that executes the following code:

```
NumericTextBox " + 1 + " .ClientID
```

Which is nonsense in most languages and looks like a mistake in any language I know of. (It's actually possibly valid Ruby, but probably not correct Ruby since Strings don't normally have a `ClientID` method.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientID = '<%=FindControl("NumericTextBox" + "1").ClientID%>';
var id = document.getElementById(clientID);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but it throws an error on browser window The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Try to reorganize your code to avoid this, e.g. building a string with your variables and then writing to the client